# Check if category has a parent in category view

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have an if statement that checks for specific category ID's and displays HTML if the condition is true. I have many categories and would like to only apply the HTML to **categories that do have a parent**.

Is there a way to check if the category has a parent?

The current code is rather heavy, and requires manual intervention when a new child category is added - there must be an easier way.

```
<?php if(in_array($_category->getId(), array(117,179,121,123))): ?>
        <p>Display this text.</p>
<?php else: ?>
        <p>Display this text instead.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

```
# not first level
if ($_category->getParentCategory()->getLevel() > 1) {

# parent is not root
if ($_category->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()) {

# not root and not first level
if (count($_category->getParentIds()) > 2) {

# has parent anchor category
if (count($_category->getAnchorsAbove()) {
```

<sup>Try `var_dump(get_class_methods($_category))` ... guess there are more possibilies.</sup>